# How to find substring in list of Python?

Tags: python

I have a list of countries:

```
country_list = ["Austria", "Brazil"]
```

Also there is some variations of string:

```
"The most beautiful country is brazil"
"Bla bla Brazil 345"
"brazil bla bla"
"34543 dsfsd bRazil blabla"
```

How to check if string has country name base list?
It is my first taks from learning book.
Which approach to use?

Comment: What is your expected output? Do you want this match to be case-sensitive? What have you tried so far? Please include this information in an edit to your original question.

Comment: I want to get matched string, it should be no sensitive

Comment: Please list your expect result, and current result

Comment: Please concretely describe (i.e. write out) your expected output, and please include this information [as an edit to your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72408073/edit).

Comment: i love brazil, i haven't been there before tho. is it really most beautiful country ever?

Answer (score 2):

here is one way :

```
sentence = "34543 dsfsd bRazil blabla"
for word in sentence.split():
    if word.capitalize() in country_list:
        print(word)
```

Comment: need to case normalize, dont think this will work alone. something like s.lower()

Comment: @rv.kvetch try this for yourself: `print('brAZil'.capitalize())`

Comment: For what `capitalize()`? Maybe to to this for list too?

Comment: @Mandalina The list is already capitalized seems like it. If not yes